# Python equivalent of php base64_encode

Tags: php, python, encoding, base64

**PHP**

```
<?php

$string = base64_encode(sha1( 'ABCD' , true ) );
echo sha1('ABCD');
echo $string;
?>
```

Output:

fb2f85c88567f3c8ce9b799c7c54642d0c7b41f6

+y+FyIVn88jOm3mcfFRkLQx7QfY=

**Python**

```
import base64
import hashlib

s = hashlib.sha1()
s.update('ABCD')
myhash = s.hexdigest()
print myhash
print base64.encodestring(myhash)
```

Output:

'fb2f85c88567f3c8ce9b799c7c54642d0c7b41f6'
ZmIyZjg1Yzg4NTY3ZjNjOGNlOWI3OTljN2M1NDY0MmQwYzdiNDFmNg==

Both the PHP and Python SHA1 works fine, but the `base64.encodestring()` in python returns a different value compared to `base64_encode()` in PHP.

What is the equivalent method for PHP `base64_encode` in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sha1.digest()` instead of `sha1.hexdigest()`

```
s = hashlib.sha1()  
s.update('ABCD')
print base64.encodestring(s.digest())
```

The `base64.encodestring` expects to the string while you give it the hex representation of it.

Answer (score 3):

`base64.b64encode(s.digest())` have correct response

Answer (score 1):

You're encoding different sha1 results in PHP and Python.

In PHP:

```
// The second argument (true) to sha1 will make it return the raw output
// which means that you're encoding the raw output.
$string = base64_encode(sha1( 'ABCD' , true ) );

// Here you print the non-raw output
echo sha1('ABCD');
```

In Python:

```
s = hashlib.sha1()  
s.update('ABCD')

// Here you're converting the raw output to hex
myhash = s.hexdigest()
print myhash

// Here you're actually encoding the hex version instead of the raw 
// (which was the one you encoded in PHP)
print base64.encodestring(myhash)
```

If you base64 encode the raw and non-raw output, you will get different results.
It doesn't matter which you encode, as long as you're consistent.

Comment: then how to get the raw output in python?

Comment: I think it's easier to just remove the `true` from the `sha1('ABC', true)`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If you remove the `true`, you should get the same in both PHP and Python.